# Get rows which have equal first column from ArrayList<Arraylist<String>>

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, arraylist, rows

I need help of getting rows that have equal 1st element in row from ArrayList < Arraylist < String > >

For example, my list structure is looks like:

```
Barcode      DepName     EventDate                 EventName
XX0123456XX  Dep1        2015-03-30 07:03:01       Sent
XX0123456XX  Dep1        2015-03-30 18:51:02       Received
XX0123456XX  Dep2        2015-03-31 01:08:04       Archived
XX9999999XX  Dep1        2015-03-30 17:22:58       Sent
XX9999999XX  Dep3        2015-03-31 12:09:43       Received
XX5555555XX  Dep1        2015-03-30 07:03:01       Sent
```

So, i want to get 1 object from equaled elements tagged like "Barcode" that contains EventDetails (DepName, EventDate, EventName). For example XX0123456XX have list with 3 EventDetails object, XX9999999XX have list with 2 EventDetails object, etc.

How can i get that rows, plz help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Map` to produce a mapping from barcode to row:

```
Map<String, List<String>> barcodeToRows = new HashMap<>();
for (List<String> item : items) {
    String bc = item.get(0);
    if (barcodeToRows.containsKey(bc)) {
        barcodeToRows.get(bc).add(item);
    } else {
        List<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpList.add(item)
        barcodeToRows.put(bc, tmpList);
    }
}
```

And then to get the rows for a barcode you can do:

```
barcodeToRows.get(bc);
```

Comment: If i use put (XX0123456XX, tmplist) will overwrite for each iteration, or not?

Comment: No, because I first check whether that key already exists in the map. If it does, then just add it to be the back of the existing value (the list) for that key.

Comment: U understood my task as I wanted, thx!!! It's helped! Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

Using Java 1.8 Streams. Criteria: Element 0 of the inner List must be the Barcode

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

    list1.add("XX0123456XX");
    list1.add("Dep1");
    list1.add("test");
    list1.add("Received");

    list2.add("XX0123456XX");
    list2.add("Dep1");
    list2.add("test2");
    list2.add("Archived");

    list3.add("XX12344XX");
    list3.add("Dep2");
    list3.add("Test");
    list3.add("Sent");

    list.add(list1);
    list.add(list2);
    list.add(list3);

    //setup done. the following line is the important one

    List<ArrayList<String>> result = list.stream().filter(l -> l.get(0).equals("XX0123456XX")).collect(Collectors.toList());

    //test output

    result.forEach(l -> {
        l.forEach(s -> System.out.print(s+" "));
        System.out.println();
        });


}
```

To your question about the loop. The Stream will run over all elements of the List. You don't need a Loop. You can create a method though.

```
public List<ArrayList<String>> getResult(List<ArrayList<String>> list, String userSearchInput){
    List<ArrayList<String>> result = list.stream().filter(l -> l.get(0).equals(userSearchInput)).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return result;
}
```

So as soon as you have the criteria from the User, call this method and the result you get is a List, only containing the columns

Comment: Thx, how can i loop this , if i have 10000 Barcodes?

Comment: You don't have to loop this. This line will give you a result `List` with all Barcodes that fit the criteria (`Barcode == given Barcode`). If you need to do this for multiple barcodes, just create a method that gets the List and the criteria, and returns the result. Then just put it in a loop

Comment: I dont know what barcode criteria i have, i have just ArrayList with that elements. So i cant give criteria. So i have to do method with in parametr like Barcode and out parameter like result of event List? and then just put it into loop of my ArrayList?

Comment: Thx for help, but it is now what i wanted